# Grant Sharepoint Access to all employees

Tags: security, sharepoint, authorization

What's the easiest way to grant access to all the employees of our company to sharepoint portal. There are some general sites which all employees have read access. So Do I have to create an AD group for all employees and add to the site or is there some better way to manage this?

Comment: as an update, you can now share with "Everyone except external users"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions are set on the site level, so I don't think there is a good way to do this.  **However**, by default new sites created with unique permissions will use the " Visitors" group as the default read-only group on on the new site.

Assuming that the Vistors group does have read-only permissions on each site, then you can edit that group from the root portal site (Site Actions > Site Settings > People and Groups) and add "Domain Users" do the " Visitors" group.

If, for some reason, all domain members are not part of the "Domain Users" group, then you can add "authenticated users" instead.  I don't like using "authenticated users" because they could be authenticated to any trusted domain or a local authority.

Comment: I don't like using "Domain Users" because there are some Domain Users who shouldn't get access to the Sharepoint site.

Comment: I agree with that too, but if your requirement is "all employees" and only employees have domain accounts.  I guess in an ideal world, you would create a new group in AD called "SharePoint Users". :)